# Imitate backend API with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a GUI for an app whose API is still being worked on. I have an idea of how it will look but it's not functional yet. I have to mimic its behaviour until it's ready.

I'm trying to do this with `$httpBackend`. I set up my installation with [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/).

---

## Attempt to Install

I'm running Angular v1.2.6.

The documentation gives me three ways of installing it:

- Google CDN at `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-mocke2e.js`
- Bower via `bower install angular-mocke2e@X.Y.Z`
- code.angularjs.org: `//code.angularjs.org/X.Y.Z/angular-mocke2e.js`

Where `X.Y.Z` is my version number.

Thing is none of those work. Google gives 404, and won't let me travel up the directories. Bower says no package available, and a 404 for code.angularjs.org. So I browsed code.angularjs.org and found that for 1.2.6, **there is no anguler-mock**

Anyway I did find a file at `https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular-mocks.js` which seems to have `$httpBackendProvider` defined in it.

When I went back to my Yeoman install - it looks like I already had `angular-mocks.js` installed.

So, question 1: **Is this what I'm looking for to use $httpBackend?**

---

### Attempt to Use

So I try to start using it in my project:

```
// Gotta manually run the app to check cookies
app.run(['$cookies', '$location', '$rootScope', '$httpBackend', function($cookies, $location, $rootScope, $httpBackend){

    // Some stuff....

    console.log($httpBackend);

}]);
```

And now my app won't start. I get the following error:
[image]

But the app *does* show me the contents of `$httpBackend`. I thought that maybe I should put it into a different module, but I don't know.

So question 2: **Is it normal that my app won't load once I throw $httpBackend into the app.run() call?**

And question 3: **Should I be putting my $httpBackend stuff into a different module while I'm testing?**

And I guess lastly is **Is this even the best way for me to test the API?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use $httpBackend to mock your services like so:

   `$httpBackend.whenGET(/\/api\/foo\/bar/).respond({some:'thing'});`
2. Your app isn't loading because it wasn't expecting a request for your partials. You can avoid that by doing something like this:

   `$httpBackend.whenGET(/^views\/.*/).passThrough();`
3. It would be good to break these out into individual modules so you can exclude them before deployment.
4. As far as it being the best solution, it depends on your needs. I would propose integrating  some build tools (Grunt, Express, Protractor, etc.) that include a local node server for testing locally. Then you could just use actual services for testing, as proposed by @Ronald91.

Comment: Well I'm using Grunt already, actually. I suppose I should ask this in a new question, but how would I include Node.js using Grunt?

Answer (score 0):

Going through a similar situation like this on a project I am working on. Never utilized httpbackend for this but we mocked out the backend services with a MongoDB instance and in our app.js file we set up the routing as followed:

```
  app.get( '/ui/orders/:orderId/details', function( req, res ){
        mongoclient.connect( mongoUrl, function(err, db){
            if( err ) throw err;
            var collection = db.collection('order-details');
            console.log( req.query);
            collection.findOne( { orderId : req.params.orderId}, function(err, docs){
                if( err ) throw err;
                console.log( "Docs...");
                console.log( docs );
                db.close();
                res.send( docs );

            } );

        });


    });
```

The service call we use to utilize this routing is

```
ourApp.factory('orderDetails', function($resource, $routeParams) {
    return function(){
        return $resource('/ui/orders/:orderId/:subSystem', {orderId: $routeParams.orderId});
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a potential answer to the "Attempt To Install" query.

Yes, angular-mocks.js is what you want. The file contains multiple modules useful for mocking. You don't have to use all of them.

For the specific case you mentioned (and the issue I'm trying to solve too, which brought me here):

1. include the file you found
2. add the following dependency to your main app module, you should be able to mock back-end requests.

   var yourApp = angular.module('app', ['ngMockE2E']);

You can use the mocks module in unit tests and in application development.